# What are the PluginGroup types that I can use when developing a Joomla plugin?

Tags: development, plugin

**When developing a plugin, what are the PluginGroup types that I can use in Joomla?**
For example, if you were to create a search plugin the `<PluginGroup>` would be `Search`.

I've tried to find a list of the types currently in use in Joomla, but so far no luck.
Another related question: **Is it possible to create your own plugin group name?**

My question was inspired by this tutorial
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla
It recommends using the PluginGroup to create a classname for the plugin like so

```
    class plg<PluginGroup><PluginName> extends JPlugin
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain PluginGroup types receive specific events. Mainly **system** group is very important in the initialization and page rendering process. Additionally, user and authentication plugins have a key role.

Finally, you can also create your own group and manage your own set of plugin events for your extension.

Check the list of events, by group [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events): [Plugin/Events - Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events).